# how to prevent a Runnable class from crashing the application?

Tags: java, jdbc, thread-safety

I'm trying to implement a (more) robust application using `Threads`.

My `JdbcAccess.java` more relevant part is:

```
protected ResultSet readfromSQLServer(String url, String instance, String port, String database, String user, String passwd, String query) throws Exception {
    try {
        // This will load the SQLServer driver
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        // Setup the connection with the DB
        String connectionUrl = "";

        if (instance != null || instance == "") {
            connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + url +  ":" + port + "/" + database + ";instance=" + instance + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + passwd;
        } else {
            connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + url +  ":" + port + "/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + passwd;
        }

        start();

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
        statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return resultSet;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running JdbcAccess thread");
    try {
        // Let the thread sleep for a while.
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start () {
    System.out.println("Starting JdbcAccess thread");
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread (this);
        thread.start ();
    }
}
```

Problem is that if it has a flawed SQL query the whole application crashes instead of the intended result of just the thread failing / dying out.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't appear to be doing anything meaningful in a background thread other than calling `Thread.sleep(50)`. What is the purpose of using threads if all you will do is call sleep on a thread that has no effect on the calling thread?

Comment: I agree with @Hovercraft, one more thing I have observed, If you have used Thread so that after start() method, so that you can have some pause by using Thread.sleep(50), if this is the case, then there is problem here, the thread which has called start() is main thread and will not get sleep and will be continue with its execution, because the sleep() has been called on a newly created thread which is different from the main thread, I want to basically understand the purpose that why you are starting this new thread. Then we can help you better.

Comment: Well, I'm not really a thread expert. Far from it, actually. The purpose of this application is to connect to a server and, via a REST call, get a list of queries to be executed. I think I have ensured each query to get a query of its own that will perform all the steps of the application. I intended to get a new thread *just* for the JdbcAccess in order to make sure if, by any reason (say database server is down), the thread would die and not compromise the application.

Comment: I find your question not very clear, and very unspecific. You might want to look at the `ExecutorService` and related classes in `java.util.concurrent`.